# How to add item to cart programmatically, with attributes in Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

So I know how to go about adding an item to the cart with PHP like this;

```
$product_nid = 2;
$some_data = NULL;

  uc_cart_empty(uc_cart_get_id());

  $data = serialize($some_data);

  uc_cart_add_item($product_nid, $qty = 1, $data, $cid = NULL, $msg = TRUE, $check_redirect = TRUE, $rebuild = TRUE);
```

but I'm uncertain how to add a product with a certain attribute/option such as if I have product "A" with options "1" and "2" I was hoping I could get a little help.
This is for Drupal 7, Ubercart 3.

Comment: figured it out, perhaps this will be of help for someone :)

Comment: `$product_nid = 2;
 $some_data = array(
'attributes' => array(
'1' => '1',
),
);
  uc_cart_empty(uc_cart_get_id());
  
  $data = serialize($some_data);
  
  uc_cart_add_item($product_nid, $qty = 1, $data, $cid = NULL, $msg = TRUE, $check_redirect = TRUE, $rebuild = TRUE);`

Comment: Both answers are wrong. $data should not be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

Taking Chris's answer an putting it in Answer format for readability.

Figured it out, perhaps this will be of help for someone :)

```
$product_nid = 2;  
$some_data = array('attributes' => array( 
                   '1' => '1', 
                  ),
             );
uc_cart_empty(uc_cart_get_id());
$data = serialize($some_data);
uc_cart_add_item($product_nid, 
                 $qty = 1,
                 $data,
                 $cid = NULL,
                 $msg = TRUE,
                 $check_redirect = TRUE,
                 $rebuild = TRUE);
```

Comment: I agree with David from the above comment, the $data should not be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

i am using ubercart in drupal 8

$session = \Drupal::service('session');

$cart_manager = \Drupal::service('uc_cart.manager');

$anonymous_cart = $cart_manager->setID($session->get('uc_cart_id'));

$sql="delete from uc_cart_products where cart_id='".$anonymous_cart."'";

db_query($sql);

$result=    db_insert('uc_cart_products')

```
        ->fields(array(
        'cart_id' => $anonymous_cart,
        'nid' => $nid,
        'qty' => $quantity,
        'changed' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d')),
        'data' => ($data),
        ))
        ->execute();
```

Comment: Quote from the question: "***This is for Drupal 7***" ...